# Как решить ошибку которая показывает на стандартную библиотеку?

Tags: c++, вывод, visual-studio-2019, lib, std-regex

Пишу небольшой лексический анализатор, но когда пытаюсь *скомпилировать*, пишется ошибка которая и показывает на стандартную библиотеку:

> C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

Код на который показывает ошибка:

```
template <class _Elem, class _Traits, class _BidIt>
basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& operator<<(basic_ostream<_Elem, _Traits>& _Ostr, const sub_match<_BidIt>& _Match) {
    return _Ostr << _Match.str(); // <- ошибка тут
}
```

Мой код (простите за грязный код, не смог повторить ошибку в чистом проекте):

```
if (this->_position.chr >= this->_origin.length()) {
    return NULL;
}

std::wsmatch match;
std::wstring temp = this->_origin.substr(this->_position.chr);
if (temp[0] == '\0')
    return NULL;
bool isMatch = false;
DS::LexemeType* type;
for (int i = 0; i < DS::types.size(); i++) {
    type = DS::types[i];
    if (std::regex_search(temp, match, type->getRegex())) {
        if (match.prefix().length() != 0)
            continue;
        std::cout << type->getName() << "(" << match[0] << ")\n";
        if (type->getID() == DS::LexemeType::ID::OTHER_NEWLINE) {
            this->_position.inLine = 0;
            this->_position.line++;
        }
        this->_position.chr += match[0].length();
        this->_position.inLine += match[0].length();
        isMatch = true;
        break;
    }
}
if (isMatch)
    return new Lexeme(match[0], *type, this->_position);

throw std::runtime_error("Wrong lexeme at " + std::to_string(this->_position.line) + ":" + std::to_string(this->_position.inLine) + "");
```

А также то как я создаю wregex объект:

```
std::wregex(L"^[0-9a-zA-Z]+")
```

Ещё раз повторю что бы убрать недопонимание, ошибка показывает не на мой код, а на код в библиотеке (и я понимаю что это из-за меня).

Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Читаем внимательно:

> C2679 binary '<<': no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>' (or there is no acceptable conversion)

```
binary '<<'
```

Ага, итак, проблема в операторе `<<`. Какая же?

```
no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type
```

Не найден оператор, который принимает справа величину типа... Какого типа?

```
std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t>>
```

Т.е. строка с "широкими" символами `wchar_t`. Или, короче говоря, `wstring`.

А теперь сами посмотрите — пытаетесь выводить `wstring` в `cout`? Вот и ответ. `wstring` и выводиться должна в `wcout`...

Кстати говоря: стоит ввести строку с кодом ошибки и проГУГЛяться в Интернет — как вы тут же получите исчерпывающую [статью](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/error-messages/compiler-errors-2/compiler-error-c2679?view=msvc-170) о ней.

Кстати, у меня в VC++ 2019 показывает именно строку кода, не библиотеки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]